# how to set title attribute of button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to assign ajax return data to button's title attribute on hover of button, so i use `$('#data_btn').title = html(returndata);`, in below code, then it unable to show any output. 
Here, #data_btn is id of button element.
Please help me regarding.

```js
$('#data_btn').hover(function(){
var val_d = $('#country').val() +"-"+ $('#city').val();
window.alert(val_d);
if(val_d != 0)
 {
 $.ajax({
        type:'post',
  url:'getdata.php',
  data:{id:val_d},
  cache:false,
  success: function(returndata){
       $('#data_btn').title = html(returndata);              
                       //$('#data_btn').html(returndata);
     }
    });
     }
 })
```

Comment: `$('#data_btn').attr('title', html(returndata));`

Comment: I replaced my code with your, but not working for me.

Comment: What does `html()` function do? Shouldn't that just be  `$('#data_btn').attr('title', returndata);`

Comment: Are you even getting into `success:` parameter??

Comment: Arghhh! It's time for me to learn _how to change baby nappies_ :) Step 1: _get nappies_.

Comment: If you solve your problem, please mark it has solve because, someone may have the same problem as you! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by trying below code, it works for me.

```
$('#data_btn').attr('title',returndata);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use `$('#data_btn').title = returnData;`, do this: `$('#data_btn')[0].title = returnData;`, `html()` is undefined, so just assign returnData to your title

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vvLm39d/)

Answer (score 0):

You never use `.title = html(returndata);` the = sign in a jQuery chain...
also, .title() is not a function.

Use the following:

```
$('#data_btn').attr('title', $(this).html(returndata));
```